# Access variables of defined in parent's init method

Tags: coldfusion

parent component's sample init method

```
   <cffunction name="init" output="false" access="public" returntype="NavigationBase">
      <cfset this.index             = 0 />
      <cfset this.length            = 0 />
      <cfset this.current           = "" />
      <cfreturn this />
   </cffunction>
   .
   .
   .
```

child component sample code

```
  <cfcomponent displayname="Navigation" output="false" extends="NavigationBase">
    <cffunction name="init" output="false" access="public" returntype="Navigation">
     <cfreturn this/>
    </cffunction>

    . 
    .
```

And if i instanciate the child component, the variables defined in parent's init function are always undefined. What I am doing here wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `init()` of the child overrides the parent `init()` method, so the variables are not getting defined anywhere. Add this line to your child `init`

```
<cfset super.init()>
```

to run the parent `init` and define/initialize those variables.